# Flutter Listview duplicates random element instead of adding new element on new data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, feed, stream-builder

I'am trying to create something like feed with Flutter and Firebase and I want to order posts by their 'postedAt' value but the problem is when I use collection.orderBy() it is not working properly. It adds new post to the random place at the feed and gives it a imageURL of random existing post (or I think it just duplicates one item in the feed). I created indexes at Firebase I tried both index types none working. The strange thing is, when I'm adding new post from the phone when my adding completed it just works fine but when listing on the other phone it shows described behaviour.

Edit: when I hot reload it works correct (last added post shows up on the top)
Edit: when I removed the orderBy method problem continued.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
      .collection("posts")
      .orderBy('postedAt', descending:true)
      .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
        }

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
             print("error:" + snapshot.error.toString());
         }



     List<Post> posts = [];

     posts = snapshot.data.docs.map((postDoc) {
          return Post.fromDoc(postDoc);
      }).toList();

     if (posts.isEmpty) {
         return Center(
            child: Text("No posts"),
          );
     }

     return ListView.builder(
          cacheExtent: 4000,
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return PostWidget(
                post: posts[index],
                );
            },
          );
        },
     )
```

my indexes:

[Composite index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJ4v.png)
[single index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEYRF.png)

screenshot of the document:
[document ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J6rP.png)

Comment: `postedAt` - is that `timeStamp` field?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of a sample document?

Comment: @Muthu Thavamani no it is not timestamp it is integer
DateTime.now().milisecondssinceepoch

Comment: I edited with the screenshot of the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue.
I thought that if it is duplicating the elements, may be it cannot seperate them. and added key paramater to `PostWidget` so it worked.